# How to plot multiple scatter plots with a global colourbar in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot, valueerror

I have a dataset from which I've calculated a value which I've used in a colourbar for a plot. See below:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how to combine it so that another parameter is plotted over it (see below:)
[image]

I want the colours to be added to the different shapes for each of the classes.

Some of the code used is below:

```
plt.figure(figsize=[12,10])
plt.scatter(x_offset1, y_offset1, s=2, c=index, cmap='jet', marker='.')
plt.scatter(x_offset2, y_offset2, s=2, c=index, cmap='jet', marker='^')
plt.scatter(x_offset3, y_offset3, s=2, c=index, cmap='jet', marker='v')
plt.scatter(x_offset4, y_offset4, s=2, c=index, cmap='jet', marker='x')

plt.colorbar()
```

This gives the error:

```
ValueError: 'c' argument has 289 elements, which is inconsistent with 'x' and 'y' with size 3.
```

I know that the 289 elements is the colour data for the whole dataset and the size 3 is the size of the first class of plots but I'm not sure how to plot the colour values of just the 3 points only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a **slice** of the `index` list. Slices work like this:

```py
slice = pizza[:2]
```

And go in the format of `list[start:stop:step]`. So, if your colors go from the **first item in the list** to the **third item**, then you would do:

```
plt.scatter(x_offset4, y_offset4, s=2, c=index[1:3], cmap='jet', marker='x')
```

Assuming `index` contains `["a", "b", "c", "d"]` (just for  the sake of an example), `index[1:3]` will return `["a", "b", "c", "d"]`. This operation does not modify the original list, so `index` will still be `["a", "b", "c", "d"]` after `index[1:3]`.